# How do I code for a login system in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ruby-on-rails

I have been researching this for a few weeks now, and am still stuck. I still don't understand how to make a custom login system. I can't get the database for mySQL for mac or PC, and Ruby on Rails would mean me to code in erb language and I don't understand erb. Can someone help?

Comment: Good one :) -1 because you did not mention scala not accepting c++ code in .net ide while deploying to SAP servers .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to setup a localhost. For Mac, to get started, you can use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) or [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). These will set up a local environment for you as well as a way to connect to a Database.

Once you've installed this, you need to create a database (MAMP and XAMPP come with an integrated Database UI called PhpMyAdmin).

Once you have set up your environment, you can start to integrate PHP.

There are various tutorials online to do this, here is a list of some simple ones:

- http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/php/how-to-make-a-login-system-with-php/
- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Basic-Login-Authentication-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html

If you have never used PHP before, I suggest you read up on the basics before diving into creating a login system, as you won't understand that much of it.

Comment: And will this still work if I publish my website???